# How do I close Atom's rustfmt popup automatically?

Tags: rust, atom-editor

I've installed `rustfmt` through `cargo` and configured `atom-beautify` to make it beautify my Rust files on save with `rustfmt`. When I type something badly, then on save a little popup shows up telling me what I did wrong. It looks like this:

[image]

When I correct my mistake and I press `Ctrl+S` to save, it saves the file, but this popup doesn't disappear, I have to manually close it down (which doesn't happen for golangs `gofmt` or cpps `uncrustify`). How can I make it close automatically?

Comment: File a new feature request on their Github tracker.